# timer in thread problem

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, timer

I have my application in which in three datagridview independently in three thread load data from wcf service. I execute in each thread timer which every second load this data.

My problem is that every time my thread go threw each thread but only like I show in method timerNowyYork_Elapsed

Any idea why this happens ? I bad lock thread?

this code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Sprawdzanie_warunków_pogodowych
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PogodaEntities entity = new PogodaEntities();
    System.Timers.Timer timerKrakow = new System.Timers.Timer();
    System.Timers.Timer timerSzczecin = new System.Timers.Timer();
    System.Timers.Timer timerNowyYork = new System.Timers.Timer();
    KeyValuePair<string, string> krakowInfo;
    KeyValuePair<string, string> szczecinInfo;
    KeyValuePair<string, string> nowyYorkInfo;

    public Form1()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        InitializeComponent();
        List<MiastoContainer> miasta = (from miasto in entity.Miasta
                                        select new MiastoContainer()
                                   {
                                       MiastoName = miasto.Nazwa,
                                       Panstwo = miasto.Państwo
                                   }).ToList();
        krakowInfo = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(miasta[0].MiastoName, miasta[0].Panstwo);
        szczecinInfo = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(miasta[1].MiastoName, miasta[1].Panstwo);
        nowyYorkInfo = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(miasta[2].MiastoName, miasta[2].Panstwo);

        ParameterizedThreadStart ptsKrakow = new ParameterizedThreadStart(PobierzKrakow);
        Thread tKrakow = new Thread(ptsKrakow);
        tKrakow.Start(this.dataGridViewKrakow);

        ParameterizedThreadStart ptsSzczecin = new ParameterizedThreadStart(PobierzSzczecin);
        Thread tSzczecin = new Thread(ptsSzczecin);
        tSzczecin.Start(this.dataGridViewSzczecin);
    }

    private void oAutorzeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AboutBox1().Show();
    }

    private void zapiszRaportToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void PobierzKrakow(object parameters)
    {
        this.timerKrakow.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timerKrakow_Elapsed);
        this.timerKrakow.Enabled = true;
        this.timerKrakow.Interval = 1000;
        this.timerKrakow.Start();
    }

    public void PobierzSzczecin(object parameters)
    {
        this.timerSzczecin.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timerSzczecin_Elapsed);
        this.timerSzczecin.Enabled = true;
        this.timerSzczecin.Interval = 1000;
        this.timerSzczecin.Start();
    }

    public void PobierzNowyYork(object parameters)
    {
        this.timerNowyYork.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timerNowyYork_Elapsed);
        this.timerNowyYork.Enabled = true;
        this.timerNowyYork.Interval = 1000;
        this.timerNowyYork.Start();
    }

    void timerNowyYork_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {  GlobalWeather.Weather weather = new GlobalWeather.Weather();
        lock (weather)
        {
            //thread always start from here
            List<object> weatherList = new List<object>();
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetTempreature(nowyYorkInfo.Key, nowyYorkInfo.Value));
           //and end here , never come any line further
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetPressure(nowyYorkInfo.Key, nowyYorkInfo.Value));
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetHumidity(nowyYorkInfo.Key, nowyYorkInfo.Value));
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetVisibility(nowyYorkInfo.Key, nowyYorkInfo.Value));
            entity.SaveChanges();

            WarunkiPogodowe warunki = new WarunkiPogodowe()
            {
                Temperatura = weatherList[0].ToString(),
                Ciśnienie = weatherList[1].ToString(),
                Wilgotność = weatherList[2].ToString(),
                Widoczność = weatherList[3].ToString(),
                DataSprawdzenia = DateTime.Now
            };
            entity.AddToWarunkiPogodowe(warunki);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            int miastoId = entity.Miasta.First(m => m.Nazwa == nowyYorkInfo.Key).id;
            Miasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe m_has_wp = new Miasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe()
            {
                idMiasto_FK = miastoId,
                idWarunkiPogodowe_FK = warunki.id
            };
            entity.AddToMiasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe(m_has_wp);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            this.dataGridViewNowyYork.Rows.Add(warunki);
        }
    }

    void timerSzczecin_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalWeather.Weather weather = new GlobalWeather.Weather();

        lock (weather)
        {
            List<object> weatherList = new List<object>();
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetTempreature(szczecinInfo.Key, szczecinInfo.Value));
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetPressure(szczecinInfo.Key, szczecinInfo.Value));
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetHumidity(szczecinInfo.Key, szczecinInfo.Value));
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetVisibility(szczecinInfo.Key, szczecinInfo.Value));
            entity.SaveChanges();

            WarunkiPogodowe warunki = new WarunkiPogodowe()
            {
                Temperatura = weatherList[0].ToString(),
                Ciśnienie = weatherList[1].ToString(),
                Wilgotność = weatherList[2].ToString(),
                Widoczność = weatherList[3].ToString(),
                DataSprawdzenia = DateTime.Now
            };
            entity.AddToWarunkiPogodowe(warunki);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            int miastoId = entity.Miasta.First(m => m.Nazwa == szczecinInfo.Key).id;
            Miasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe m_has_wp = new Miasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe()
            {
                idMiasto_FK = miastoId,
                idWarunkiPogodowe_FK = warunki.id
            };
            entity.AddToMiasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe(m_has_wp);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            this.dataGridViewSzczecin.Rows.Add(warunki);
        }
    }
    void timerKrakow_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalWeather.Weather weather = new GlobalWeather.Weather();

        lock (weather)
        {
            List<object> weatherList = new List<object>();
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetTempreature(krakowInfo.Key, krakowInfo.Value));
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetPressure(krakowInfo.Key, krakowInfo.Value));
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetHumidity(krakowInfo.Key, krakowInfo.Value));
            weatherList.Add(weather.GetVisibility(krakowInfo.Key, krakowInfo.Value));
            entity.SaveChanges();

            WarunkiPogodowe warunki = new WarunkiPogodowe()
            {
                Temperatura = weatherList[0].ToString(),
                Ciśnienie = weatherList[1].ToString(),
                Wilgotność = weatherList[2].ToString(),
                Widoczność = weatherList[3].ToString(),
                DataSprawdzenia = DateTime.Now
            };
            entity.AddToWarunkiPogodowe(warunki);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            int miastoId = entity.Miasta.First(m => m.Nazwa == krakowInfo.Key).id;
            Miasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe m_has_wp = new Miasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe()
            {
                idMiasto_FK = miastoId,
                idWarunkiPogodowe_FK = warunki.id
            };
            entity.AddToMiasto_has_WarunkiPogodowe(m_has_wp);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            this.dataGridViewKrakow.Rows.Add(warunki);
        }
    }
}

class MiastoContainer
{
    string miastoName;

    public string MiastoName
    {
        get { return miastoName; }
        set { miastoName = value; }
    }
    string panstwo;

    public string Panstwo
    {
        get { return panstwo; }
        set { panstwo = value; }
    }

    public MiastoContainer()
    { }

    public MiastoContainer(string miasto, string panstwo)
    {
        this.MiastoName = miasto;
        this.Panstwo = panstwo;
    }

    public void Add(MiastoContainer item)
    {
        ((ICollection<MiastoContainer>)this).Add(item);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your locks are completely useless. As you are locking on an object that you just created, each lock will have it's own identifier and does not affect each other at all.

You need all locks that should exclude each other to use the same object as identifier.

Comment: So how to force each thread to do his work in timer synchronous?

Comment: Create a new variable in the form: `object sync = new object();` and use that for your locks.

Comment: and pass in this object everything that is use in thread and not belongs to thread?

Comment: @netmajor: No, it's just an empty object that is used to synchronise the locks: `lock(sync) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Timers.Timer` lets you set the `SynchronizingObject` so that it will invoke the callback on the UI thread. When you create your timers, write:

```
this.timerKrakow.SynchronizingObject = this;
```

The timer's elapsed event will then be invoked on the UI thread. That eliminates the need for locks in your event handlers.

You could do the same thing, by the way, with a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which always invokes the event handler on the UI thread.

The drawback to raising the event on the UI thread is that it might block the user interface. It depends on how much time is spent in the event handler. If your event handler is very quick, then this isn't a problem. If it will take 100 milliseconds to process the event handler, though, you probably don't want to do it on the UI thread.

If you elect not to do it on the UI thread, you need to synchronize access to the UI. The timer event handler can't just modify user interface elements. Instead, you need to call [this.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) so that any UI modification is done on the UI thread.

I strongly suggest that you NOT use `System.Timers.Timer`. As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) states:

> The Timer component catches and
>   suppresses all exceptions thrown by
>   event handlers for the Elapsed event.
>   This behavior is subject to change in
>   future releases of the .NET Framework.

In other words, if there is a bug in your event handler that throws an exception, you will never know it. I suggest using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but (unless I'm mistaken) the timer callbacks occur in the ThreadPool (or the GUI thread, dependent on usage), so starting them in different threads is pointless.

Comment: in that case those callbacks will raise an Exception (Cross Thread operation not valid) when they try to access a control that was created by the UI Thread ... like the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are accessing DataGridView directly from another thread. You should not do that. UI controls must always be called from the UI thread. You can use the `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface to pass the data into correct thread.

```
this.dataGridViewNowyYork.Invoke(new Action(() => {
    this.dataGridViewNowyYork.Rows.Add(warunki);
}), null);
```

Comment: I should use this code instead this.dataGridViewNowyYork.Rows.Add(warunki);
 ?